# .NET Linking items in a multiple list controls

Tags: .net, sql-server, drag-and-drop, listbox

First off, we're using Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server and this is about a desktop app.

So, my team and I have been designing an app that allows a user to work with SQL Server tables to create custom views to use in reporting. This app was needed because we are moving from Access to SQL Server, but the training for Management Studio and the paradigm shift from Access to SQL Server will be time consuming.

The app we've been working on is small, but will be used as a temporary transition app between Access and SQL Server. Basically it has a visual designer that looks and feels like Access, but works with SQL Server and is customized to our business model.

I understand that we could just force the whole group (50+ users) to do any DB work in Management Studio, but we're hoping to slowly move in that direction over the next year.

What I am looking for is literally one of the last pieces that we need. **I am looking for a listbox/view/grid that can be used to link fields in a table**. I can code it myself, but that will be time-consuming and I was hoping something already exists that is either free or inexpensive as we only need the functionality for this one use.

I have linked to a picture that demonstrates what we're looking for. Basically using drag and drop to connect lines from one item in a list to an item in another list, but be clickable and move with the fields when/if the scrollbar is moved.

I'm hoping this exists but my searches so far have proven fruitless. Thank you in advance for any help.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use of SSRS, this basically the default reporting tool of Microsoft.  If the users who like access I think you can link Access to work whit SQL Server as Backend.

Yo may want to look this link [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fbf2ce4e-624f-42c9-9b2e-0647aaef5248/create-link-line-between-2-listbox-items)